# Why doesn't this XPath query work as I assumed? (searching for elements with some @ while excluding those with other @)

Tags: xpath, dita, oxygenxml

I have the following query (XPath 2.0):

```
//xref[contains(@href,'#') and @class='- topic/xref ' and @type!='step' and @type!='fig' and @type!='substep']
```

As you can see, I want to find topic/xref elements with a hash in their href attribute. I want to exclude ceratin types of elements.
Problem is, the above query does not display elements with @outputclass='expandable'

I had to run a seperate one to identify them:

```
//xref[contains(@href,'#') and @outputclass='expandable']
```

Why does the first, longer query, do not display those elements? I also tried contains(@class='- topic/xref ) instead of @class=' - topic/xref ' and it didn't help.

Comment: Add relevant `XML` source and specify required output as your issue is not quite clear

Comment: @Andersson It's a huge DITA map with dozens of topics, and not really one that I can share.
Here's an example of what I want to find:
1. <xref href="2012121213534449584.dita#" outputclass="expandable" class="- topic/xref "/>
2. <xref href="2012121213534449584.dita#" class="- topic/xref "/>

Comment: So you want elements with `class="- topic/xref "` and `outputclass="expandable" `, right? and how about *while excluding those with other @*? What to exclude?

Comment: I also want `class= '- topic/xref '` that do not have `outputclass='expandable'`. In fact, I want all `class='- topic/xref'` that do not have any of the following in their @type: fig, substep, table, whether they have `outputclass='expandable'` or not, but have a # character in their @href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below `XPath`:

```
//xref[@class="- topic/xref " and contains(@href, "#") and not(@type=("fig", "substep", "table") or @outputclass="expandable")]
```

that will return `xref` elements with `class="- topic/xref "` and `#` in `href` attribute but doesn't have `type` attribute with values `"fig", "substep", "table"` or `outputclass` attribute with value `"expandable"`

Comment: I actually need the expandable ones. I modified what you sent and eventually used this:
`//xref[@class="- topic/xref " and contains(@href, "#") and not(@type=("fig", "substep", "table", "step"))]`
to do what I needed to do. Unlike my original query, this one did not omit the ones with @outputclass = expandable from the results.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your XML source, but I suspect you were expecting to retrieve elements having no `@type` attribute. However, the condition `@type!='XYZ'` is true only for an element that has an `@type` attribute whose value is something other than 'XYZ'. If my guess is correct, you intended `not(@type='XYZ')`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `!=`! In my case, I don't want to omit the @type attribute completely; it's a huge set of files that's existed for years and had many contributors, and it keeps surprising things in elements.
Coupled with @Andersson's answer, I ended up with a query that did what I needed today.